# What is Reserving Capacity in dictionary swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

what Reserving capacity actually does and what advantage does it give to us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As its name suggest it reserves enough space to store the specified number of key-value pairs.

If you are adding a known number of key-value pairs to a dictionary, use this method to avoid multiple reallocations.

This method ensures that the dictionary has

- unique
- mutable
- contiguous storage

with space allocated for at least the requested number of key-value pairs.
Calling the reserveCapacity(_:) method on a dictionary with bridged storage triggers a copy to contiguous storage even if the existing storage has room to store minimumCapacitykey-value pairs.

```
mutating func reserveCapacity(_ minimumCapacity: Int)
```

Here minimumCapacity - 
The requested number of key-value pairs to store.